Attribute [SIZE_GRID_ROW_ID] is missing
Estoy intentando sincronizar un producto con MercadoLibre y recibo el siguiente error:
json
Copiar código
{
"message": "Validation error",
"error": "validation_error",
"status": 400,
"cause": [
{
"department": "structured-data",
"cause_id": 2611,
"type": "error",
"code": "missing.fashion_grid.grid_row_id.values",
"references": ["item.attributes"],
"message": "Attribute [SIZE_GRID_ROW_ID] is missing"
}
]
}
He verificado que en los atributos del producto ya estoy enviando lo siguiente:
[attributes] => Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => color
            [name] => color
            [value_name] => rojo, azul
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => SIZE
            [name] => SIZE
            [value_name] => 36, 37
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => SIZE_GRID_ID
            [name] => SIZE_GRID_ID
            [value_name] => 2548646
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => GENDER
            [name] => GENDER
            [value_name] => Sin genero
        )
)

Sin embargo, MercadoLibre sigue indicando que falta el atributo SIZE_GRID_ROW_ID. ¿Es necesario incluir este atributo de forma adicional o configurar algo en el producto para que sea aceptado? ¿Alguien podría ayudarme a entender cómo resolver este error y qué valor debería asignar al atributo SIZE_GRID_ROW_ID?
¡Gracias de antemano!
